# jqTransform: How to keep <select> value after form submit

Tags: validation, forms, jqtransform

### My problem:

Retaining the value of form elements after form submission is a common inquiry. I've researched a few solutions relating to select boxes but seeing as how I'm using the popular jqTransform for the aesthetic quality of my form, the said solutions aren't applying.

### What I've tried:

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904932/how-to-keep-the-selected-value-of-the-select-box-after-form-post-or-get) stackoverflow thread suggested the following approach:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('name').value = "<?php echo $_GET['name'];?>";
</script>
```

### What happened:

Nothing. Therein lies my problem. jqTransform replaces the select box with an unordered list.

### An idea:

One of the list items contained contains a link distinguishing itself as selected:

```
<a href="#" index="0" class="selected">Please select an option...</a>
```

I'd be greatful if anyone could should suggest a means of targeting the "transformed" select box / list or any other means of retaining the desired value after submission.

Answer (score 0):

it is probably because you have do the jqTransformation first before changing the select box value. Try change the value before jqTransformation