# PHP combobox result after submit

Tags: php, combobox

i've tried many solutions from the website, but noone give me the result.

I have a combobox, and i insert data from mysql db

after pressing "submit button", the combobox refresh, but restart from first data and not from selected,

hereunder my code,

can someone help me?

```
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM courier");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {

 echo "<option  ". (($_POST['NAZIONE'] == $row["NAZIONE"]) ? 'selected ' : '') ."value=\"".$row["NAZIONE"]."\">".$row["NAZIONE"]."</option>";
  }

echo'</select> <br> <input type="submit" value="Proceed">';

mysql_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: Don't use the `mysql_*` functions for new projects, they are deprecated as of PHP 5.5 and will be removed in future.  Use instead the `mysqli_*` functions or `PDO`.

Comment: To which page you are posting? the same page or some other page

Comment: check dis out :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904932/how-to-keep-the-selected-value-of-the-select-box-after-form-post-or-get

Comment: Hi Edwin Alex, i'm posting in same page, after submit, the page refresh, and the combobox restart with first value

Answer (score 0):

you can set selected value to $_SESSION variable and then you can get that selected value